# Is it possible to access current column data on conflict

Tags: postgresql, ecto

I want to get such behaviour on inserting data (conflict on id):

- if there is no model with same id in db do INSERT
- if there is entry with same id in db and that entry is newer (updated_at field) do NOT UPDATE
- if there is entry with same id in db and that entry is older (updated_at field) do UPDATE

I'm using Ecto for that and want to work on constraints, however I cannot find an option to do so in documentation. Pseudo code of constraint could look like:
`CHECK: NULL(current.updated_at) or incoming.updated_at > current.updated_at`
Is such behaviour possible in Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

That should be simple using the `WHERE` clause of `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, entry) VALUES (42, '2021-05-29 12:00:00')
ON CONFLICT (id)
   DO UPDATE SET entry = EXCLUDED.entry
      WHERE mytable.entry < EXCLUDED.entry;
```

Answer (score 0):

> PostgreSQL does not support CHECK constraints that reference table
> data other than the new or updated row being checked. While a CHECK
> constraint that violates this rule may appear to work in simple tests,
> it cannot guarantee that the database will not reach a state in which
> the constraint condition is false (due to subsequent changes of the
> other row(s) involved). This would cause a database dump and reload to
> fail. The reload could fail even when the complete database state is
> consistent with the constraint, due to rows not being loaded in an
> order that will satisfy the constraint. If possible, use UNIQUE,
> EXCLUDE, or FOREIGN KEY constraints to express cross-row and
> cross-table restrictions.
>
> If what you desire is a one-time check against other rows at row
> insertion, rather than a continuously-maintained consistency
> guarantee, a custom trigger can be used to implement that. (This
> approach avoids the dump/reload problem because pg_dump does not
> reinstall triggers until after reloading data, so that the check will
> not be enforced during a dump/reload.)